# Вопрос про мультиязычность сайта

Tags: локализация

Здравствуйте,  возникла нужда добавить версию сайта на английском языке. Следовательно возник вопрос,  на каком языке будет выводится сайт в поисковых системах?  Можно ли сделать так чтоб если человек "гуглит" из к примеру США,  ему выводилось то же описание (description) сайта на английском,  м аналогично для русских из россии. То есть вопрос конкретно не про то как сделать сайт на другой версии языка,  так как уже есть подготовленные константы перевода слов,  а как сделать так чтобы поисковик различал эти версии.

P. S.  делать поддомен .ru не вариант,  нужно именно переключение языка внутри сайта,  как в том же Вконтакте и тд.  Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Излюбленный приём для веб-разработчиков — ориентироваться на заголовок HTTP `Accept-Language`. В случае с поисковыми машинами он не подходит, поскольку этот заголовок устанавливает поисковый робот. У Google скорее всего установлен английский язык, а у Yandex — русский.

Вы должны предоставить две страницы с разными URI, чтобы поисковики смогли проиндексировать обе и выдавать их в поисковой выдачи для разных языков.

Страницы могут находиться на разных доменах (**foo.com/page.html**-**foo.ru/page.html**) или в одном домене (**foo.com/en/page.html**-**foo.com/ru/page.html**). Главное, страницы на разных языках должны ссылаться друг на друга с помощью тега `link` с установленным атрибутом `hreflang`.

Подробности №1: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru

Подробности №2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hreflang